# redirect /dev/stdin as parameter to node script

Tags: node.js, bash, shell, raspberry-pi

I have a node script which would normally be called like

```
node emitter.js "some message"
```

Now i am using trl_fm and multimon_ng to receive and decode some radio messages. I managed to redirect the output to /dev/stdin by using a command like this:

```
rtl_fm -M fm -f 81.200M -s 21 | multimon-ng -t raw -a POCSAG2400 -f alpha /dev/stdin
```

This way I am getting kind of a console-log where the decoded messages are printed out on a line each when they have been received.

What I am trying to achieve is to call `emitter.js` everytime a message is received and pass this message as an parameter to `emitter.js`, but i just can't figure out how to get this to work.

things I have tried:

```
rtl_fm -M fm -f 81.200M -s 21 | multimon-ng -t raw -a POCSAG2400 -f alpha /dev/stdin | node emitter.js

rtl_fm -M fm -f 81.200M -s 21 | multimon-ng -t raw -a POCSAG2400 -f alpha /dev/stdin > node emitter.js

rtl_fm -M fm -f 81.200M -s 21 | multimon-ng -t raw -a POCSAG2400 -f alpha /dev/stdin >> node emitter.js
```

Is there any way to get this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can hook up everything with a bit of shell scripting:

```
#!/bin/sh

rtl_fm -M fm -f 81.200M -s 21 | \
multimon-ng -t raw -a POCSAG2400 -f alpha /dev/stdin | \
while read message
do
  node emitter.js "$message"
done
```

Or you could modify `emitter.js` so it would read messages from stdin instead of using command line arguments, in which case you could pipe to the Node process directly (and it also would remove the need to start a new Node process for each incoming message).

Answer (score 0):

This was used to send messages over websocket but the piping should work the same

```
let rtlInitialized = false;
let multimon;  // Declare here but initialize in startMultimon

const startMultimon = () => {
    multimon = spawn('multimon-ng', ['-t', 'raw', '-a', 'POCSAG512', '-a', 'POCSAG1200', '-a', 'POCSAG2400', '-a', 'FLEX', '-f', 'alpha', '--timestamp', '-'], {
        stdio: ['pipe', 'pipe', 'pipe']
    });

    if (!multimon || !multimon.stdin) {
        console.error('Failed to initialize multimon-ng or its stdin is not available.');
        return;
    }

    multimon.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
        console.error(`multimon-ng error: ${data}`);
    });

    multimon.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
        const lines = data.toString().split('\n');
        lines.forEach(line => {
            if (!line || line.length == 0 || line == null) { return; }
            console.log(`Multimon data: ${line}`);
            const parsedMessage = parseMessage(line);
            console.log(`Parsed message: ${JSON.stringify(parsedMessage)}`);
            if (parsedMessage) {
                wss.clients.forEach(client => {
                    client.send(JSON.stringify(parsedMessage));
                });
            }
        });
    });

    multimon.on('close', (code) => {
        console.log(`multimon - ng process exited with code ${code} `);
        // Handle the error or restart the process if necessary
    });

    // Directly connects rtl_fm's output to multimon-ng's input
    rtl_fm.stdout.pipe(multimon.stdin);
};

const rtl_fm = spawn('rtl_fm', ['-f', '929.600M', '-l', '50', '-M', 'fm', '-s', '22050']);
if (!rtl_fm.stdout) {
    console.error('Failed to initialize rtl_fm');
    return;
}

rtl_fm.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
    const message = data.toString();
    console.error(`rtl_fm error: ${message} `);

    if (!rtlInitialized && message.includes("Sampling at")) {
        rtlInitialized = true;
        startMultimon(); // this function will handle the piping of rtl_fm's output to multimon-ng's input
    }
});
```